# How can I prove that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{i+1}}{(i+1)!} = e^z - 1?$

Tags: power-series

How can I prove that
$$ \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{z^{i+1}}{(i+1!)} = e^z - 1 $$

knowing that 
$$ \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{z^i}{i!} = e^z  $$

Comment: I dont see whats there to prove when you know that.

Comment: @KingTut, the two equations are different. The bottom one is only for additional information, not necessarily part of the proof.

Comment: Given that liberty, why would anyone not use it.

Comment: Strategy: when you see sums written with $\sum$ write out the first few terms followed by an ellipsis ($\ldots$). That will often show you what's happening.

Comment: Thank you, @EthanBolker. Will try it out on paper now...

Comment: Isn't $ \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{z^{i+1} } { (i+1)! } = \frac{z}{1} + \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^3}{3!}.... = e^z$??

Comment: @RVC No, that sum is $e^z-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^i}{i!}=1+\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{i+1}}{(i+1)!}$$ because $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^i}{i!}=1+\frac{z^1}{1!}+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\dots=1+\left (\frac{z^1}{1!}+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\dots\right )=1+\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{i+1}}{(i+1)!}$$

Comment: Thank you, @cansomeonehelpmeout. But this is exactly my question, just rearranged... How did you take the 1 out of the sum?

Comment: @RVC I've edited my answer. Does it help?

Answer (score 2):

Reindex: 
$$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{z^{i+1}}{(i+1)!}=
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{z^{i}}{i!}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{z^{i}}{i!}-1=e^z-1
$$

Comment: why $-1$ and not $+1$ ?

Comment: Dario one term is missing in first sum so add and subtract.

Comment: now I see it, thanks

Comment: @qbert, terribly sorry, but when you reindexed to i=1 to \infty, what happend to the i=0 term? or if you set the new index i=i+1, why didn't it start from -1?